# Active Vs Proactive

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, adjectives

As you can see in my provided dictionary definitions, there is hardly a definite distinction between the two adjectives at least here in my case.
I was wondering how these two differ semantically and which one suits better in my case and why?

> **Question:** What is the best way to find the best partner? 
> **Answer:** I believe that there's someone out there for just about everyone and all we need to do is go find this person. So, the best solution is to be ........ 
> One way would be meeting people doing what you love.

**a.** [active](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/active) 
**b.** [proactive](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/proactive)

Comment: I see very different defintions:  active: "busy with a particular activity" ...  proactive: "taking action by causing change and not only reacting to change"    One is about being "busy", the other "take action first, not just reacting".   I think an answer will just restate the dictionary defintions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proactive means to be active in advance of something.

[Merriam-Webster *proactive*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proactive)

> acting in anticipation of future problems, needs, or changes

It can be contrasted with *active*, meaning exhibiting activity of any kind, and *reactive*, meaning acting in response to something.

I think *proactive* fits your sentence best: get out there and do something, instead of just waiting for something to happen, or reacting to others' initiatives.